# Excel's Data Validation Drop-Down Lists in MS Access

Tags: excel, ms-access

Is there a way to forbid entering values that are not included in drop-down lists in MS Access? In Excel, a warning pops up that the value you're entering is wrong. However, MS Access lets you enter any value despite my connecting a particular column to another table of a column of values through the Lookup Wizard.

Could I, in any way, achieve that in MS Access (but preferably without VBA)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set the "Limit To List" property of the ComboBox to "Yes".

[image]

Comment: as far as I understand, comboboxes in forms have this property. But unfortunately, no such a property in a table's columns' properties

Comment: as far as I understand, tables do not have "drop-down lists"...  What "drop-down lists" are you referring to?